# Default path for file import Julia

Tags: io, path, julia

I have created a package and am now creating my tests within the package. For one test my inputs are a set of files and my outputs will be a different set a files created within the test.

I am saving the input files in the test directory of my package and would like to save the output files there too. Since others may run this test, I do not want to specify the input/output file location using my own path eg /home/myname/.julia/v4.0/MyPackage/test/MyInputFile.txt
How do I specify that the input location is within the package's test folder?

So basically how do I tell Julia to look in the packages's folder under the test directory and not have to worry about specifying the entire path including user name etc?

For example currently I have to say

```
readtable(/home/myname/.julia/v4.0/MyPackage/test/MyInputFile.txt, separator = '\t', header = false)
```

But I'd like to just be able to say

```
readtable(/MyPackage/test/MyInputFile.txt, separator = '\t', header = false)
```

so that no matter who the user of the package is and where they may store the package, they can still run the test?

I know that LOAD_PATH gives the path Julia looks for packages but I can't find any information on where it looks when importing files.

Comment: `joinpath(Pkg.dir("MyPackage"), "test")` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GnimucK mentioned in a comment, a better solution is

```
dirname(@__FILE__)
```

Why is this better? A package could be installed and used from somewhere else (not the standard package directory). `Pkg.dir` is "stupid" and does not know better. This is rare, of course, and in most cases it won't matter.

Comment: How would I actually use this? For example if I want to find the directory path of a file named "thisfile.jl" ? I've tried dirname(@__thisfile.jl__) and dirname(thisfile.jl) and dirname(@thisfile.jl) but none of these work.

Comment: @user3061923 Put `@__FILE__` literally. It's a macro that resolves to the current file name.

Comment: So I did exactly that dirname(@__FILE__) and the return I got was just " ", how does that help me? I really am not understanding what is going on here. Why is it returning " "  and how does simply typing that tell Julia that I'm looking for the file MyPackage/test/MyInputFile.txt specifically ?

Comment: @user3061923 It is very strange that `dirname(@__FILE__)` is returning " ". Could you ask that in a separate question? Provide details about your OS and how you are invoking the script.

Answer (score 2):

`joinpath(Pkg.dir("MyPackage"), "test")` is what you need.

Comment: in general, `dirname(@__FILE__)` will give you the absolute path of the .jl file, even though you're not working on a package.